# How to initialize a variable on an usertask in activiti

Tags: java, activiti

I have a workflow with different `usertasks`, I would like to handle a `state` variable per `usertask`.

On creation of the `usertask` I would like to initialize the variable (e.g. `CREATED`). Later I will set the variable to `SENT` and `READ`.

According to the documentation I could do something like that, using a `taskListener`:

```
<userTask id="WorkJob.task" name="WorkJob.task" activiti:assignee="${assignee}" activiti:dueDate="${dueDate}">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" >
          <activiti:field name="script" stringValue="${state='CREATED'}">
          </activiti:field>
          <activiti:field name="language" stringValue="JavaScript" />
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

For this I would need to provide a script engine which I don't have right now. Is there an easier way to initialize a task variable?

Maybe something like this:

```
<activiti:variable name="state" value="CREATED"/>
```

Maybe using expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Use JDK 7+. you don't have to provide any additional script engine, use the one shipped instead. then use the following.

```
<userTask name="Step_1" id="UUID" activiti:formKey="10" activiti:assignee="$INITIATOR">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" event="create">

            <activiti:field name="language">
                <activiti:string>
                    <![CDATA[javascript]]>
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>

            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
                    <![CDATA[task.setVariable("state", "CREATED");]]>
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>

        <activiti:taskListener class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" event="complete">
            <activiti:field name="language">
                <activiti:string>
                    <![CDATA[javascript]]>
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>

            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>
                    <![CDATA[task.setVariable("state", "COMPLETE");]]>
                </activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```